# Any shortcuts to get some test ethers for goerli test net?

Tags: ether, testnets, goerli

let me know if you have any other ways to get some test ethers apart form(https://faucet.goerli.mudit.blog/) tweet post, fb post link and mycrypto request.

Comment: Where do you get your daily faucets now?

Answer (score 1):

I use [Chailink faucet](https://faucets.chain.link/goerli) quite often, and it's working. But it gives you only 0.1 ETH at time, so you may need to farm a bit :)

Comment: Thank's for reminding me, it is working.

Answer (score 1):

There's a Paradigm [sponsored faucet](https://faucet.paradigm.xyz/) that will give you a proper amount of ETH and some extra ERC20 tokens to play with. For some networks it may say pending refill but Görli seems to be on.

Comment: It seems to be only once per user

Answer (score 1):

https://goerlifaucet.com/

Sign up and you can get 0.5 ether every 24 hour.

Answer (score 0):

https://goerli-faucet.pk910.de/

here it is, more than 1 eth per hour

Answer (score 0):

Seconding https://goerlifaucet.com/! It's built by Alchemy so it's not spam and reliable - you can get more testETH daily if you need it